# Why should I use HTML validators along with Angular Form Validators

Tags: angular

In the Angular documentation, its is recommended to use HTML validators (eg `required`) along with Angular validators eg. `Validators.required`. The reason is:

> Use these HTML5 validation attributes in combination with the built-in validators provided by Angular's reactive forms. Using these in combination prevents errors when the expression is changed after the template has been checked.

But I didn't understand it well. Why should I use both? Isn't just Angular's form validators sufficient?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? The reason given in the quote is indeed impossible to understand.

Comment: Infact this above note is in Angular’s Reactive form section  - https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms